# libdvdread: Can't seek to block

Tags: 12.04, dvd

I am trying to read a DVD.
libdvdcss is installed.

VLC plays the DVD fine for about 20 minutes before stopping suddenly. Totem, AcidRip, DVD::RIP all fail. I think that lsdvd sums up the problem:

```
$ lsdvd
libdvdread: Using libdvdcss version 1.2.12 for DVD access
libdvdread: Can't seek to block 2002266
libdvdread: Can't seek to block 2002266
libdvdread: Can't seek to block 3740904
libdvdread: Can't seek to block 3740904
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 2 (VTS_02_0.BU).
Can't open ifo 2!
```

What is going wrong? The DVD has no scratches.

Answer (score 4):

1. Check the output of the `mount` command to make sure that no other CD/DVD devices are mounted. If you booted with a disk in your drive and ejected the disk using the drive drawer button, this will not properly unmount the drive reference.
2. Follow these installation instructions to make sure you have the latest libdvd library: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs
3. Mount the drive by hand to make sure that it reads: http://brainwreckedtech.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/bug-libdvdread-cant-seek-to-block-on-second-layer/

   Basically these commands: `mkdir -p /media/$LOGNAME/dvd; mount /dev/sr0 /media/$LOGNAME/dvd`
4. Launch gxine with that location: `gxine /media/$LOGNAME/dvd`

Best of luck.

Comment: +1 for the `mount` tip.  Eject from the files/folders app, then try again.  This is a way of clearing the problem if you have previously ejected using the drive drawer button.

Comment: lifesaver even in 2016. is this bug being fixed?

Answer (score 3):

I just had this problem with "Django Unchained". I could partially fix it. Partially, because the video sometimes "sticks" for a second or so. And after 1.5hours it crashed :-/

Try setting "No disc menus" checkbox in the "open disk" menu in `vlc`:

[image]

Alternatively, you might want to try `smplayer`.